# How to achieve ASP.NET Core Web API documentation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

with ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0 we could abe to manage documentation of API using `HelpPage`. Is this feature continuing with ASP.NET Core or has introduced new approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much better alternative called "Swashbuckle.Swagger". It's excellent and being using it for more than year for Web API 2 as well as ASP.NET Core Web API.

For more details [Read this article](https://damienbod.com/2015/12/13/asp-net-5-mvc-6-api-documentation-using-swagger/)

Comment: Is swagger is the only one or still Microsoft has its any other own library?

Comment: Honestly I never explored MS options for HELP in ASP.NET Core, they might have it (not sure) or might come up. But even they use swagger in their demo as well